# Weak derivative and integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and define

$$h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(y)dy$$

Prove that $h'=f$ where $h'$ is the weakly derivative of $h$.

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, the weakly derivative $g$ (if exists) satisfies:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)\varphi'(t)dt = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t)\varphi(t)dt$$

for all $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0$. (Infinitely differentiable functions with compact support)

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0$, suppose that $\text{supp}(\varphi) \subseteq [a,b]$ with $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)=0$. Then we have:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(x)h(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x)h(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left( \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy \right) dx $$

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(x)h(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left( \lim_{x_0 \to -\infty} \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx = \lim_{x_0 \to -\infty} \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left(  \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx $$

Operating the integrals:

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left(  \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx = -\int_{a}^{x_0} \varphi'(x) \left( \int_{x}^{x_0} f(y)dy \right) dx + \int_{x_0}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left( \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx $$

By Fubini's theorem:

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left(  \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx = -\int_{a}^{x_0} f(y)dy \left( \int_{a}^{y} \varphi'(x)dx \right)  + \int_{x_0}^{b} f(y)dy \left( \int_{y}^{b} \varphi'(x)dx \right)  $$

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left(  \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx = - \int_{a}^{b} f(y)\varphi(y)dy$$

So:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'h = \lim_{x_0 \to -\infty} \int_{a}^{b} \varphi'(x) \left(  \int_{x_0}^x f(y)dy \right) dx =  - \int_{a}^{b} f(y)\varphi(y)dy = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \varphi $$

Then we have $h' = f$. My proof is correct?

Answer (score 2):

$h$ is bounded and absolutely continuous so $h\phi$ is absolutely continuous. [Because  $\phi$ is also bounded and absolutely continuous]. Hence $h(y)\phi(y)-h(x)\phi(x)=\int_x^{y} (h\phi)'=\int_x^{y} (h\phi'+f\phi)$ since $h'=f$ almost everywhere. It follows by letting $y \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty$ that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (h\phi'+f\phi)=0$ which is what we have to prove.

Comment: How prove that the wekly derivative of $h$ exists?. Then you use the fundamental theorem with weakly derivative right?.

Comment: @Leo If we find $g$ such that $\int f \phi'=-\int g\phi$ for all $C^{\infty}$ functions $\phi$ with compact support then the weak derivative exists and equals $g$. In this case there is an obvious candidate for $g$, namely $f$.

Comment: Yes, thanks!. My proof is correct?

Comment: You did not justify interchange of integral and limit w.r.t $x_0$. @Leo

Comment: Is there any way to justify? or is it not true?

Comment: @Leo It can be justified using DCT. But there are still gaps in your argument. After Fubini's Therem you applied integration by parts . The Calculus version of this requires continuity of $f$. I think some deeper measure theory involving absolute continuty is essential for this.

Comment: I don't use integration by parts. $\varphi'$ is continuous so $\int_{a}^{b} \varphi' = \varphi (b) - \varphi(a)$.

Comment: @Leo Sorry, I misunderstood your argument. Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thanks, what is DCT?

Comment: DCT is Dominated Convergence Theorem. Use the fact that $\int_{x_0}^{x} f(y)dy$ is bounded and apply this theorem to justify the interchange of integral and limit. @Leo

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy